# Federated authentication in Windows Azure using Facebook as IP

Tags: facebook, azure, acs, federated-identity

All answers to my question lead to a year old document (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg185919.aspx) which is not correct anymore - the section "To obtain a Facebook Application ID and Facebook Application Secret" describes the process than cannot be used on today's Facebook site for developers.

I am hoping  that someone who has Facebook experience can get me the "current version" of this 7 steps long process described as:

1. Create a Facebook account at http://facebook.com
2. Navigate to http://www.facebook.com/developers/  (*my note: this is wrong - the url should be developers.facebook.com*)
3. On the Facebook | Developers page, click the + Set Up New Application button, and then follow the instructions. (*What instructions*)
4. On the Facebook | Edit <> page, click the Web Site link on the left. (*No such link*)
5. Copy Application ID and Application Secret. You will use these when you configure Facebook as an identity provider on the ACS Management Portal in the next step
6. Specify your fully qualified domain name (FQDN) URL to your namespace, including the leading HTTPS. Your namespace will be different.
7. Click the Save Changes button

The step 6 is the biggest problem - it is the insertion of Azure ACS specific information into Facebook's world and was not able to find the field on Facebook App form creation where this belongs to. Obviously, I do not know anything about Facebook's app creation.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies @nikivancic for not being able to try it out for myself, but I think what you're looking for is in the application settings.

In Facebook

- Click the edit button on the top right for the application you have
  just created
- In the left hand menu, under settings, click on Basic
  (you might already be there)
- Under 'Select how your app integrates with Facebook', click the 'Website with Facebook Login' option

This will reveal a textbox to enter the url to redirect to on login - I believe this is where you need to enter the URL to your namespace in ACS.

Again - apologies for not being able to test it right now, but try following this and see if that works

Comment: How wonderfully obvious advice - I have to admit that I completely failed to recognize that I am dealing with options for "how my app integrates with Facebook" data item, so I kept forcing the round peg in a square hole.